# Crosstab to remove duplicate lines

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can't seem to find the sql logic to cross tab data results.

Let's say this is my data-set, 2 columns (Department name and Name)

```
Dept1 . Bob
Dept2 . Mark
Dept1 . Bill
Dept2 . Carol
Dept3 . Amy
Dept1 . Melissa
Dept1 . John
```

What I want to see in the output is

[image]

The column count would be based on the highest number of people in a department.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-Server 2012 you can do this:

Assumption: you have a maximum of 4 names per department and you are using SQL-Server 2012

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ([DepartmentName] VARCHAR(20) , Name VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('Dept1','Bob'),

('Dept2','Mark'),

('Dept1','Bill'),

('Dept2','Carol'),

('Dept3','Amy'),

('Dept1','Melissa'),

('Dept1','John')
```

Query:

```
 SELECT [DepartmentName], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM 
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DepartmentName] ORDER BY [DepartmentName]) AS rn FROM #temp
) p
PIVOT
(
MAX (Name)
FOR rn IN
( [1], [2], [3], [4] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.[DepartmentName];
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That works, thanks.  I just wish there was a way that a temp table didn't have to be created.  Bill may change departments and it would be nice if the program just automatically would update instead of having me update the values in the temp table.

Thanks though for the reply.